# Does the saying "If you cannot prevent an oppression, at least announce it to everyone?" belong to Hazrat Ali (R.A.)?

Tags: source-identification, ali

I am seeing this saying quoted quite often nowadays, that is attributed to Hazrat Ali (R.A.)

> If you cannot prevent an oppression, at least announce it to everyone?

Does this saying really belong to Hazrat Ali (R.A.)? If so, where is it documented, and can you also include original Arabic saying?

If not, does this saying belong to another credible Islamic figure?

Comment: It reminds me of **3 levels of Iman** `When you see something bad happening then stop it by hand or stop it by talk or just think it bad`.

Answer (score 1):

*I found a narration from Imam Ali (peace be upon him) that he said:*

> Whoever see  an oppression, and be silent, he himself is as a partner
>   of that oppression.

(I think it could be what you asked. Of  course I reckon there must not be the precise sentence which you asked, since to be honest, I looked up to some extent, but I did not find such a sentence. So I reckon it could be the Hadith which you asked (but in some other words somewhat). Because it could convey its purpose.

Besides, unfortunately I could not find this in tradition in Arabic, anyhow I hope it be helpful for you.

---

**Reference:**

- [http://forum.talarebourse.com](http://forum.talarebourse.com/f14/t54454-print-551.html)